# Tool to Generate ER diagrams from Views in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, erd

Is there any third party tool (free or paid) which could be useful in generating Entity Relationship Diagram from the views in SQL Server 2005/2008 or higher version?

For example,I have a view in my database and I wish to generate ER Diagram based on all the tables that are being referred in the view.

Let me know for any doubts

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use a Java-based free tool named [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/). It basically works with any RDBMS as long as it has a JDBC connector.

I have discovered this while scratching my own itch, and also created a detailed post on it. Can be found here: http://blog.kmonsoor.com/generate-er-diagram-from-sql-database/

Summary:

> - First of all, your system should have Java runtime properly
>     installed. SchemaSpy is a .jar file. Get it:
>     http://sourceforge.net/projects/schemaspy/files/
> - JDBC connector to
>     you DB. Make sure to match your DBMS version.
> - Also, SchemaSpy
>     depends on GarphViz to generate the ER-diagrams, so you need to be
>     installed it on your system. http://www.graphviz.org/Download..php
> - target DB instance must be up & running
>
> Now, this command will do the magic:
>   `$ java -jar ./schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar -t pgsql -host 127.0.0.1:5432 -db your_database_name \
>                                   -u your_DB_user_name -p your_password -s public \
>                                   -dp ./database_specific.jdbc3.jar \
>                                   -o output_folder`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this, many outlined below. The easiest approach would be to use SQL Server's own diagrammer (described on the link below).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224825(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in SQL Server Management Studio:

Connect your DB, open Object Explorer and right click your view and select "Design". This gives you the graphical view designer, which is a pretty good ER diagram of your view.

Answer (score -2):

use **mysql workbench**. There are tools already provided to generate ER diagram directly from database.

Comment: It helps to add tables only to ER diagram. Do you know which tool to use for adding views as well to the ER diagram.